# Javascript slideshow won't stop

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a web page with a slide show activated by clicking a button. When I click the button the first time, I want the user to be prompted with how fast they want it to change to the next image before actually running the slide show. The next time the button is clicked, I want the slideshow to stop. Right now the first part is working, but when I click it a second time it just shows the prompt again and doesn't stop the slideshow. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Here is my code for the given function:

```
function slideShow(){
var temp2 = 0;
  if (temp2 == 0){
    var speed = prompt("How fast would you like to the slideshow to go?");
    var timerID = setInterval("clock()",speed);
    temp2 = 1;
  }
  else if (temp2 == 1){
  clearInterval(timerID);
  temp2 = 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: `homework` tag is deprecated, you are discouraged to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move

```
var timerID
```

to outside of the function declaration.

```
var timerID
function slideShow(){
var temp2 = 0;
  if (temp2 == 0){
    var speed = prompt("How fast would you like to the slideshow to go?");
    timerID = setInterval("clock()",speed);
    temp2 = 1;
  }
  else if (temp2 == 1){
  clearInterval(timerID);
  temp2 = 0;
  }
}
```

That would be the easiest way. You are basically just throwing that variable away everytime you call that function.

---

Just so other advice. You don't really ever want to use a string in setInterval.

Comment: It's still prompting me on the second click and the slideshow doesn't stop like it is supposed to.

Comment: Figured it out. Also had to put temp2 outside of the function. Thanks for leading me in the right direction.

Comment: yeah, sorry both variables need a "higher" or promoted scope.